# Bootstrap table: change row color by data value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, html-table

How do I change the color of a row in a bootstrap table, depending on the row's data value. (I want the text to be red if the date column is older that today).

I'm good with C++ and C#, but new to JS and JQuery

Here is the code:

```
<table data-toggle="table"
    data-url="GenerateJSonEmailList.php"
    data-sort-name="stargazers_count"
    data-sort-order="desc">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="idProspects" 
                data-sortable="true">
                    ID
            </th>
            <th data-field="Prenom" 
                data-sortable="true">
                    Prénom
            </th>
            <th data-field="Nom" 
                data-sortable="true">
                    Nom
            </th>
            <th data-field="EmailAddress" 
                data-sortable="true">
                    Adrese courriel
            </th>
            <th data-field="DateNextEmail" 
                data-sortable="true">
                    Date
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: (depending on the row's data value) what is the meaning of this?

Comment: var theDateYouWant = $('selectorForDatCol').text(); that 'selectorForDatCol' could be a class, or an id... even 'tr td:last-child' or 'tr td:nth-child(n)' in javascript you can get the content of a dom-element as a variable using element.innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Assign class for your date field and loop it through jquery. Convert the date-field value into Date format then compare with the current date.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="idProspects" 
            data-sortable="true">
                ID
        </th>
        <th data-field="Prenom" 
            data-sortable="true">
                Prénom
        </th>
        <th data-field="Nom" 
            data-sortable="true">
                Nom
        </th>
        <th data-field="EmailAddress" 
            data-sortable="true">
                Adrese courriel
        </th>
        <th data-field="DateNextEmail" 
            data-sortable="true">
                Date
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>      
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td class="datefield">05/11/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>      
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td class="datefield">05/23/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>      
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td class="datefield">05/18/2017</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var CurrentDate = new Date();
   $('.datefield').each(function(){
      var SelectedDate = new Date($(this).text());
      if(CurrentDate > SelectedDate) {
          $(this).css('color', 'red');
      }
   });
 });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yz107b7j/)